Ideal approach to copy a dll to Solution folder, AppX folder and Publish Folder
I have a VS soution of WINUI C++ APP. It has multiple shared projects and static projects, recently I have created a DLL project(B) which is referenced to another project(A)? How to make sure the DLL project is copied to the solution configuraion folder so that DLL symbols are loaded when .exe is lauched and It should also get copied to APPX folder when it is packaged (or) even launched from VS.
I tried adding a post-build event on Project(A) to copy to $(SolutionDIR) but this doesn't seems better soution because it is not copying to APPX folder and importantly when there are any changes to DLL project(B) DLL is not updated at $(SolutionDIR). So, I think post-built event should be in Project(A) but still how to makes sure to add it to APPX folder?

$(LayoutDir) is the APPX folder, you can try to use xcopy /y /d "$(SolutionDir)$(IntDir)" "$(LayoutDir)" in your ProjectA.

does this also be part of packaging will check.

If you need to include DLL in the package, you need to add the dll file to the winui3 project and set the Content property to true. https://i.sstatic.net/oTpJVGJA.png GitHub thread:https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6365#issuecomment-1344766084
